# Lighttpd rewrite but keep orginal host

Tags: php, lighttpd

I have multiple domain names like:
`exempale.com` and `anotherexempale.net` and `thisistotallydifferent.org`

I want to redirect all visitors to one domain lets say `exempale.com` but I want to keep the original domain so you get `exempale.com/thisistotallydifferent.org` or a PHP variable is also good.

I want to do this to monitor which domain is found or used to most. The other problem I have is it is a list of a lot of domains and I don't want to write a rewrite rule for every single one of them.

The server is running centos 7, lighttpd and php7.1.
I'm willing to switch to apache or nginx if this is not possible with lighttpd.

Comment: Please mention what you tried so far.

Comment: I tried $HTTP["host"] !~ "^(www\.)?exampale\.com" {
        url.redirect = (
                "^/(.*)" => "http://www.exampale.com/%2"
        )
}

Comment: Why not simply enable mod_accesslog and log the incoming requests to the other domains?  Then just redirect the other hosts to the one domain you want the users to see, as you have done in the condition test in the comment above.